# Remove numerous characters including underscore

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a large number of files in numerous directories with this type of naming convention: "filename_yymmdd.csv", etc. I need to remove the underscore and the yymmdd. So the new file name would be "filename.csv". i need to recursively search through for .csv files and remove the date and underscore in powershell V2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```psh
$pattern = '(.*)_\d{6}(.csv)'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? { $_.Name -match $pattern } |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $pattern, '$1$2' }
```